# HTTP запрос Java Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

сформировал http запрос
каким методом его отправить на сервер?

```
 Document doc2 = null;
 String strURL2 = MinusBal;
 doc2 = Jsoup.connect(strURL2).post();
```

приложение вылетает!
после запроса сервер отправляет ответ "200", если запрос прошел удачно.

что делаю не так?

Comment: "что делаю не так" - Да то же, что и остальные, аж отвечать скучно. Во-первых - не умеете пользоваться logcat и даже try-catch (если бы умели, то не ограничивались словом "вылетает"). Во-вторых, возможно, запрос шлете в потоке UI или пермишн забыли, но без первого пункта это кофейная гуща.

Comment: Действительно. Неплохо бы привести нам ошибку, ибо без нее вам никто ничего не скажет. Возможно, вы не добавили в манифест разрешение на использование интернета. Честное слово... С другой стороны, мб вам попробовать готовы библиотеки на отправку запросов? Неплохой считается OkHttp. Вот пример https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial. В своем приложение, запросы я шлю через нее. P/S/ Старайтесь писать более развернутый вопрос, описывая подробно проблему, с приведением деталей.

Comment: спасибо всем. разобрался. сделал через AsyncTask. все заработало. как то сложноват JAVA , на питое по проше все. Ну ни чего пудем пробовать, падать и снова пробовать.